# How to check cross platform write permissions to a folder (.Net 7)

Tags: .net, linux, windows, macos, acl

Currently I am using the following solution to check write access permission to folder.

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;

public static bool CheckWriteAccessToFolder(string folderPath)
{
    try
    {
        // Attempt to get a list of security permissions from the folder. 
        // This will raise an exception if the path is read only or do not have access to view the permissions. 

        var di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        DirectorySecurity ds = di.GetAccessControl();
        return true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The issue is that GetAccessControl method is specific to Windows platform (Warning  CA1416  This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'FileSystemAclExtensions.GetAccessControl(DirectoryInfo)' is only supported on: 'windows')

What is the solution that would work cross platform (Linux, Mac and Windows) ?